# Plotting a dataframe with many columns, whilst making the rows the legend

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am trying to plot a dataframe of the format of the one linked below.

I realise this is probably easy, but I'm very stuck.

I would like to plot so that the years/ column names are the x axis, the values in each column are represented by the y axis, and for the country names to be a legend. This should result in a line graph of the different data.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Post the data instead of image. A few rows of data.

Comment: Thanks, will do next time

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all countries and plot them using `matplotlib`, like so:

```py
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    plt.plot(df.columns, df.iloc[i])
```

You can also use the `plt.legend()` function to set a legend. You might have to replace the `NaN` values with 0 first otherwise it might give an error.

Comment: Thanks, I went for the transpose method, but may well give this a try

Answer (score 0):

Look into the transpose method: [transpose()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas.DataFrame.transpose).

This writes the columns as rows and vice versa. Afterwards you should be able to plot the DataFrame by column.

Comment: Thanks, I used this method and it solved the issue :)